# Telling a pet to get out of the way

Tags: traducción, animales

## English

If I want to tell my cat to get out of the way, I can say “scram!” or “scoot!” In Spanish, how can I tell my cat to go away quickly? Merriam-Webster’s Spanish dictionary says that scram=largarse, so would I say “te larga”?

Another possibility is “irse.” I found conflicting conjugations for that, so I don’t know whether it would be “te ve” or “te vete.” But “irse” seems to mean only, “go away,” and I want a brief command that means “go away quickly.” “Te ve rápidamente” is too verbose to say to a cat.

## Español

En inglés, puedo decirle *“scram!”* o *“scoot!”* a mi gato si quiero se vaya rápidamente. ¿En español, qué debo decir? Quizás ¡te larga! o «irse» → ¡te ve! o ¡te vete! (No puedo conjugar «irse».) Busco un mandato breve.

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/28180/how-do-you-call-a-pet-in-spanish

Comment: Correct ways to say that to a pet (because it would sound rather rough towards a human) are: **¡Fuera!** / **¡Largo!** / **¡Vete!** / **¡Quítate!** / **¡Hazte!** / **¡Sáquese!** / **¡Vámonos!**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres conjugar un verbo (como `ir`) puedes consultarlo en la página de la [RAE, la Real Academia (de la lengua) Española](http://www.rae.es/). Puedes usar el buscador para encontrar la palabra que deseas consultar en el diccionario, y si es un verbo, como ["Ir"](http://dle.rae.es/ir), puedes darle al botón de "conjugar" que se encuentra en la esquina superior izquierda para ver las conjugaciones de ese verbo.

El imperativo de "ir" es "ve", así que puedes ordenarle "ve**te**" a tu gato (no "te ve", el pronombre tiene que ir después del verbo). Igual con "lárga**te**!" Este último es un [verbo pronominal](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbo_pronominal) y requiere el pronombre en su conjugación, pero le podrías ordenar igualmente "largo!", que es una forma de abreviar "Largo de aquí".

También podrías decirle "Quita!", como forma abreviada de "Quita/quíta**te** de en medio". "Desaparece" o "esfúmate"([Esfumar](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=esfumar), con el sentido de *marcharse* es otro verbo pronominal) también tienen la connotación que tratas de encontrar con *"scram"* y *"scoop"*.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the imperative like this: **¡Vete!**, or **¡Lárgate!**.

Another way to say it is **¡Fuera!**, which is a bit rougher.

Comment: ¡**fuera** (perro)! se usa también en Argentina

Answer (score 4):

Para ahuyentar a los gatos en el DLE está [zape](https://dle.rae.es/?id=cN4hdsb):

> `De *ṣabb*, palabra no árabe, pero usada entre los árabes y empleada hoy en Marruecos.`
>
> 1. interj. coloq. U. para ahuyentar a los gatos ...

Answer (score 3):

En Chile:

> Ándate, fuera, muévete.

Nunca "vete" o "lárgate", se reconoce que el hablante no es chileno.

Quizás la forma más habitual en Chile sería "*¡sale!*", que es una incorrección, pero nadie diría la forma correcta "*¡sal!*".

Answer (score 2):

En Colombia he escuchado la palabra *chite* usada para ahuyentar mascotas (perros especialmente). Su significado según la [fuente](http://www.senalcolombia.tv/component/glossary/Diccionario-1/C/Chite-853/) es:

> Palabra usada para espantar a los perros.
>
> Ej: "¡Quítenme ese bicho que me muerde! ¡Chite perro!"

Answer (score 2):

Every time I hear Spanish speakers in Texas say get outta here in Spanish they say, "¡Vete!" It's just like saying, "Git!"

Answer (score 2):

En México:

> ¡Quítate!

or

> ¡Quítate de ahí!

(Se puede agregar "Por favor".  La gran ventaja de esto es que así vas entrenando a tus hijos a hablar con cortesía.)

Answer (score 1):

En España, y aplicado únicamente a perros, se usa la voz **tuso** a menudo pronunciada alargando la *u*: **¡tuuuuso!**

[Diccionario IEDRA](https://iedra.es/palabras/tuso)

> tuso 1.
>
> 1. interj. U. para llamar o espantar a los perros.
> 2. m. coloq. perro.

Answer (score 0):

The RAE lists the following terms for shooing various animals:

| Animal | Shooing sound |
| --- | --- |
| chickens | [ox](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=ox), [os](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=RGvao1K) |
| dogs | [za](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=za), [zuzo](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=zuzo), [chucho](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=91vbETk), [tuso/tusa](https://dle.rae.es/tuso) |
| cats | [zape](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cN4hdsb) |
| misc. | [huichó](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=huich%C3%B3) `Chile` |