# How do you call a pet in Spanish?

Tags: palabras-raras, animales, onomatopeyas

In English, to call (for example) a cat, one usually whisper/whistles something like:

> *psh-wsh-wsh*

or calls

> *Here, kitty kitty kitty...*

Are there similar words used in Spanish? Do they vary for different animals?

Comment: Here we use these expressions to call... **dogs : Ks ks ks ks** / **cats: bistu bistu bistu**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RAE lists a rich variety of different animal calls used by people for different domestic animals:

| Animal | call | shoo | lie down | charge | misc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **dog** | [tuso, tusa](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=az1kudx),<sup>1</sup> [tus](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=tus),<sup>3</sup> [to](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=to),<sup>3</sup> [cuz](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=cuz),<sup>3</sup> [cito](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=cito) | [za](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=za), [zuzo](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=zuzo), [chucho](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=91vbETk) | [cucha](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=BXSttUU) | [azuzar](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=azuzar) |  |
| **chicken** | [pira](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=T8OGhMj),<sup>3</sup> [pita, pitas](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=TEDBWi6)<sup>3</sup> | [ox](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=ox), [os](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=RGvao1K) |  |  |  |
| **cat** | [mio](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=mio), [mino](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=mino), [miso](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=miso), [miz](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=miz),<sup>2</sup> [morro](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=PrY17Xz), [morra](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=PrFRj9T),<sup>1</sup> [cucho, cuchito](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=BYOXjpU)<sup>`Chile`</sup> | [zape](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cN4hdsb) |  |  |  |
| **pig** | [chin](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=chin), [cuchí](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=cuch%C3%AD), [cochi](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=cochi),<sup>3</sup> [cuino](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=cuino)<sup>`Asturias`</sup> |  |  |  |  |
| **Hunting birds** | [hucho](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=hucho), [huchohó](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=huchoh%C3%B3) |  |  |  |  |
| **Bulls, cows, oxen** |  |  |  | [jau](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=jau) | [jo](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=MUqKUQQ)<sup>`León`</sup> |
| **Horses** |  |  |  | [apá](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=ap%C3%A1) | [so](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=Y3F7kCf)/cho, [huesque](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=huesque), [ria](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=ria) |
| **Misc** | [che](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=8gKEtDx) | [huichó](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=huich%C3%B3)<sup>`Chile`</sup> |  | [jau](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=jau), [arre](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=3geCpGQ#KpLuogm), [harre](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=harre)<sup>2</sup> |  |

---

<sup>1. Specifically female animals.</sup>
<sup>2. Archaic.</sup>
<sup>3. Also used repeatedly.</sup>

Comment: I don't agree at all with RAE. Nobody would use those in Spain. In fact, "chucho" is perro, not gato.

Comment: @FGSUZ I imagine a lot of these are dialectal (some say this explicitly) or have fallen out of use in modern Spanish (especially as society has become increasingly urban and less agrarian). Note that the word to call a cat is *cucho* though, not *c**h**ucho*.

Comment: I have not heard ANY of these in Colombia. :)

Answer (score 2):

Personally and people I know when they try to get the attention of an unknown animal (in the south of Spain):

Cat: *misi* or *mini*

Dog: *tubi*

Usually they say them multiple times (*misi misi misi...*).

Comment: Huh, I've never heard tubi - what country/region is this?

Comment: South of Spain. Maybe you heard Tobi